# Resetting Wordpress Panoramic Theme by OutTheBox to it's default settings without losing posts

Tags: wordpress, default

My website is slow because of the theme. I am using the Panoramic theme by OutTheBox and I want to reset the theme to it's default settings without losing the posts and URLs. Can someone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> If you are considering resetting your WordPress theme to default, be
> aware that this will completely remove all of your current theme
> settings and restore the theme to its original state. This cannot be
> undone, so be sure that you really want to do this before proceeding.

First, go to your WordPress admin area and find the “Themes” link at the top.

Then, click on the “Theme Settings” link next to the theme name. This will take you to the theme’s settings page.

On the theme settings page, you’ll find a “Default Theme” option in
the “General” tab. Click on this to open the default theme’s settings
page.

Here, you’ll find a list of all the WordPress themes installed on your site. Click on the “Reset Theme” button next to the theme you want to reset to its default settings.

Once the resetting process is complete, your theme will be back to its default settings. To confirm that everything is working as expected, you can check the theme’s documentation or contact the theme’s creator for help.

I suggest that before you start this process you create a backup of your database and your files.